# How do I conform to a protocol with associatedtype in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

It's such a shame that I really have no idea with this. I have this project that was developed by someone else and it's using [TRON library.](https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON)

My question is pretty straightforward. How do I conform to a protocol with an `associatedtype`. I know how to write a protocol and conform to it just like with `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Here's the code of TRON's protocol:

**Serializer.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

/// The type in which all data and upload response serializers must conform to in order to serialize a response.
public protocol ErrorHandlingDataResponseSerializerProtocol : DataResponseSerializerProtocol {
    /// The type of serialized object to be created by this `ErrorHandlingDataResponseSerializerProtocol`.
    associatedtype SerializedError

    /// A closure used by response handlers that takes a parsed result, request, response, data and error and returns a serialized error.
    var serializeError: (Alamofire.Result<SerializedObject>?,URLRequest?, HTTPURLResponse?, Data?, Error?) -> APIError<SerializedError> { get }
}
```

And I'm trying to conform to that protocol like so:

```
 class CustomErrorHandlingSerializer: ErrorHandlingDataResponseSerializerProtocol {

 }
```

I need to conform to that because there is a function here that needs an `ErrorHandlingDataResponseSerializerProtocol`,

[image]

I have tried reading the library's documentation and even their migration guide. It's either they really do not have a straightforward example on their usage OR I just don't understand their documentation.

1. https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON/blob/master/Docs/4.0%20Migration%20Guide.md
2. https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRON author here.

Most of the time you don't need to implement this protocol, because responseSerializer is provided by default, if your models are JSONDecodable or Codable. I assume you were using older version of TRON with SwiftyJSON, in that case you would probably need to call request in this way:

```
let request : APIRequest<...,...> = tron.swiftyJSON.request("path")
```

If you really want to implement custom response serializer, you would basically need to implement two protocols - `ErrorHandlingDataResponseSerializerProtocol` and `DataResponseSerializerProtocol`, which both contain one associatedtype and a variable.

You can use typealias, but it's better to let Swift infer associatedtype from variable signature. You can take a look at [Response Serializers doc](https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON/blob/master/Docs/Response%20serializers.md) for reference, i updated it to latest syntax.

Comment: Super awesome! Thank you so much! :) adding `xxx.swiftyJSON` works! Good thing I posted a ticket on your repo <3

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what type of object will be returned by the `serializeError` property. There are two ways to do it:

1. Define a `SerializedError` subtype of your class, or:
2. Use `typealias` to point `SerializedError` to the appropriate type that your `serializeError` property will provide.